# Cast any c# List to Array type

Tags: c#, arrays, casting

I'm writing a WPF converter.  I know the `value` is going to be a `List` of arrays, and I really just want to get each element into a `DataTable`.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    // value may be List<bool[]> or List<double[]> or List<string[]>...
    Array array = value as List; // pseudocode
    // ...

    var table = new DataTable();
    // ... 

    var row = table.NewRow();
    row[i] = array.GetValue(i, j);
    // ...
}
```

Is there any way to cast the original `value` into a generic array?  Or some sort of list?  Open to new ideas here.

Comment: If you know `value` is going to be a list of arrays, then cast it that way: `(List<Array>)value`.

Comment: value.ToArray() not works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example of using the non-generic collection interfaces for interfacing with collections of unknown elements.

If you *know* for certain that you will receive a list then use the `IList` interface. Otherwise it will be safer to use `IEnumerable`.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    // Convert to non-generic list
    var list = value as IList;
    // null check, etc...

    var table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add(...)
    // Add columns... 

    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        var row = table.NewRow();
        // Convert list item to non-generic array
        var array = item as Array;

        // Iterate the array elements
        for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            row[i] = array.GetValue(i);
        }

        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

See also:

- [IList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx)
- [Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can cast to an `IList` and from there cast each item to an `Array`.

```
IList listOfArrays = value as IList;
...
row[i] = ((Array) listOfArrays[i]).GetValue(j);
```

You can also make the `value` parameter to be of type `IList`:

```
public object Convert(IList value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
   ...
   row[i] = ((Array) value[i]).GetValue(j);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  It was a long day yesterday and I was obviously over-thinking the problem. Also, the class having inherited `Convert` method from `IValueConverter` will not allow me to change the argument type.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may come handy. This is a an Object Shredder Utility that I use:

I believe the original code was from MSDN but I have modified slightly to accommodate `nulls` for `System.DateTime` types.

***Caveat**: I would not use this frequently as it does consume resources and takes some time.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Project.Util
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for ObjectShredder
    /// </summary>
    public class ObjectShredder<T>
    {
        private System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] _fi;
        private System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] _pi;
        private System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, int> _ordinalMap;
        private System.Type _type;

        // ObjectShredder constructor.
        public ObjectShredder()
        {
            _type = typeof(T);
            _fi = _type.GetFields();
            _pi = _type.GetProperties();
            _ordinalMap = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Loads a DataTable from a sequence of objects.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="source">The sequence of objects to load into the DataTable.</param>
        /// <param name="table">The input table. The schema of the table must match that 
        /// the type T.  If the table is null, a new table is created with a schema 
        /// created from the public properties and fields of the type T.</param>
        /// <param name="options">Specifies how values from the source sequence will be applied to 
        /// existing rows in the table.</param>
        /// <returns>A DataTable created from the source sequence.</returns>
        public DataTable Shred(IEnumerable<T> source, DataTable table, LoadOption? options)
        {
            // Load the table from the scalar sequence if T is a primitive type.
            if (typeof(T).IsPrimitive)
            {
                return ShredPrimitive(source, table, options);
            }

            // Create a new table if the input table is null.
            if (table == null)
            {
                table = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
            }

            // Initialize the ordinal map and extend the table schema based on type T.
            table = ExtendTable(table, typeof(T));

            // Enumerate the source sequence and load the object values into rows.
            table.BeginLoadData();
            using (IEnumerator<T> e = source.GetEnumerator())
            {
                while (e.MoveNext())
                {
                    if (options != null)
                    {
                        table.LoadDataRow(ShredObject(table, e.Current), (LoadOption)options);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        table.LoadDataRow(ShredObject(table, e.Current), true);
                    }
                }
            }
            table.EndLoadData();

            // Return the table.
            return table;
        }

        public DataTable ShredPrimitive(IEnumerable<T> source, DataTable table, LoadOption? options)
        {
            // Create a new table if the input table is null.
            if (table == null)
            {
                table = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
            }

            if (!table.Columns.Contains("Value"))
            {
                table.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(T));
            }

            // Enumerate the source sequence and load the scalar values into rows.
            table.BeginLoadData();
            using (IEnumerator<T> e = source.GetEnumerator())
            {
                Object[] values = new object[table.Columns.Count];
                while (e.MoveNext())
                {
                    values[table.Columns["Value"].Ordinal] = e.Current;

                    if (options != null)
                    {
                        table.LoadDataRow(values, (LoadOption)options);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        table.LoadDataRow(values, true);
                    }
                }
            }
            table.EndLoadData();

            // Return the table.
            return table;
        }

        public object[] ShredObject(DataTable table, T instance)
        {

            FieldInfo[] fi = _fi;
            PropertyInfo[] pi = _pi;

            if (instance.GetType() != typeof(T))
            {
                // If the instance is derived from T, extend the table schema
                // and get the properties and fields.
                ExtendTable(table, instance.GetType());
                fi = instance.GetType().GetFields();
                pi = instance.GetType().GetProperties();
            }

            // Add the property and field values of the instance to an array.
            Object[] values = new object[table.Columns.Count];
            foreach (FieldInfo f in fi)
            {
                values[_ordinalMap[f.Name]] = f.GetValue(instance);
            }

            foreach (PropertyInfo p in pi)
            {
                values[_ordinalMap[p.Name]] = p.GetValue(instance, null);
            }

            // Return the property and field values of the instance.
            return values;
        }

        public DataTable ExtendTable(DataTable table, Type type)
        {
            // Extend the table schema if the input table was null or if the value 
            // in the sequence is derived from type T.            
            foreach (FieldInfo f in type.GetFields())
            {
                if (!_ordinalMap.ContainsKey(f.Name))
                {
                    // Add the field as a column in the table if it doesn't exist
                    // already.
                    DataColumn dc = table.Columns.Contains(f.Name) ? table.Columns[f.Name]
                        : table.Columns.Add(f.Name, f.FieldType);

                    // Add the field to the ordinal map.
                    _ordinalMap.Add(f.Name, dc.Ordinal);
                }
            }
            foreach (PropertyInfo p in type.GetProperties())
            {
                if (!_ordinalMap.ContainsKey(p.Name))
                {
                    // Add the property as a column in the table if it doesn't exist already.
                    DataColumn dc = table.Columns[p.Name];
                    //Added Try Catch to account for Nullable Types  
                    try
                    {
                        dc = table.Columns.Contains(p.Name) ? table.Columns[p.Name]
                        : table.Columns.Add(p.Name, p.PropertyType);
                    }
                    catch (NotSupportedException nsEx)
                    {
                        string pType = p.PropertyType.ToString();
                        dc = pType.Contains("System.DateTime") ? table.Columns.Add(p.Name, typeof(System.DateTime)) : table.Columns.Add(p.Name);
                        //dc = table.Columns.Add(p.Name); //Modified to above statment in order to accomodate Nullable date Time 
                    }




                    // Add the property to the ordinal map.
                    _ordinalMap.Add(p.Name, dc.Ordinal);
                }
            }

            // Return the table.
            return table;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Nice generic use of DataTables.

Comment: you're most welcome. I know that it does not address your question exactly as you wanted to 'shred' List of Arrays, but thought this may either provide you with the a template for what you want to so or that you might be able to modify the input of list of arrays to a list of objects